# Term for the review of available technologies

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase analogous to "literature review", but referring to the review of technologies available to solve a particular problem.

That is, what would I call the process of comparing the features and functionality of available software or hardware with the intention of selecting one to be implemented in a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in the industry and we use **technology review** and **technology audit**.

Single words that give technical significance (to at least my groups) are **audit** and **scoping**.

Comment: Would this also apply to the review of available software packages within a programming language?

Comment: @metasequoia - That is basically 80% of the auditing and scoping that we do.

Answer (score 0):

When I've performed such a review of options within a given context, I'll consider the term 'survey'. To me it leaves the door open a bit — it isn't necessarily a comprehensive, exhaustive examination of all options, but gives the reader an idea of what is out there, what the contenders are, etc.